# How to define a range query depending on the count?

Tags: mysql

The tuples in my table look like this: (value, date, attribute). Now I want to query the database and get a range, but not depending on the date, but on the count "the last x entries in the range of ...". The following example shall clarify: I have a time bar where all entries with the attribute="x" are ordered by the date column, so the date of point s and t are smaller that the date in point 0 and the date in point x and y are bigger than in point 0, of course. All the points have attribute = "a".

```
      s        t  0  x        y
------|--------|--|--|--------|------> t
```

Now I want to get all entries with the following characteristics: Get all entries from s - t and x - y, where attribute="a" and choose s and t in a way that I get 60 entries in this range, choose t in a way that 5 entries are between t and 0, and x and y respectively.

Here is a sample data:

```
(xyz, 01.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 02.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 01.02.2000, b)
(xyz, 03.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 01.02.2000, b)
(xyz, 04.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 06.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 01.02.2000, b)
(xyz, 07.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 01.02.2000, b)
(xyz, 10.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 12.02.2000, a)
```

The desired output for date = 06.02.2000 and range s-t = 3, t-0=1 would be

```
s = (xyz, 01.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 02.02.2000, a)
t = (xyz, 03.02.2000, a)
(xyz, 04.02.2000, a) NOT because between t and 0 should be 1 free
0 = (xyz, 06.02.2000, a)
```

And in the other direction, the "right" direction on the time bar exactly the same...

At the moment I use two queries with order by date and limits (5, 60), but I would guess that there is a better way... I only don't know this way ;-)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only practical way is to use an UNION between two LIMIT'ed queries, one sorted in ascending order, the other in descending order. This also because there is no guarantee that there is the desired number of rows in any one of the two intervals.